# How minimal can an SVG be?

Tags: optimization, svg

I just reduced this SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>

<svg viewBox="0 0 480 150" style="background-color:#ffffff00" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" x="0px" y="0px" width="480" height="150">
    <path d="M 0 35.5 L 6.5 22.5 L 16 37 L 23 24 L 34.8 43.7 L 42.5 30 L 50.3 47 L 59.7 27.7 L 69 47 L 85 17.7 L 98.3 39 L 113 9.7 L 127.7 42.3 L 136.3 23.7 L 147 44.3 L 158.3 20.3 L 170.3 40.3 L 177.7 25.7 L 189.7 43 L 199.7 21 L 207.7 35 L 219 11 L 233 37 L 240.3 23.7 L 251 43 L 263 18.3 L 272.7 33.3 L 283 10 L 295 32.3 L 301.3 23 L 311.7 37 L 323.7 7.7 L 339.3 39 L 346.3 25.7 L 356.3 42.3 L 369.7 15 L 376.3 25.7 L 384 9 L 393 28.3 L 400.3 19 L 411.7 38.3 L 421 21 L 434.3 43 L 445 25 L 453 36.3 L 464.3 18.3 L 476.2 40.3 L 480 33.5 L 480 215 L 0 215 L 0 35.5 Z" fill="#175720"/>
</svg>
```

To this:

```
<svg height="150" width="480"><path d="m0 35.5l6.5-13 9.5 14.5 7-13 11.8 19.7 7.7-13.7 7.8 17 9.4-19.3 9.3 19.3 16-29.3 13.3 21.3 14.7-29.3 14.7 32.6 8.6-18.6 10.7 20.6 11.3-24 12 20 7.4-14.6 12 17.3 10-22 8 14 11.3-24 14 26 7.3-13.3 10.7 19.3 12-24.7 9.7 15 10.3-23.3 12 22.3 6.3-9.3 10.4 14 12-29.3 15.6 31.3 7-13.3 10 16.6 13.4-27.3 6.6 10.7 7.7-16.7 9 19.3 7.3-9.3 11.4 19.3 9.3-17.3 13.3 22 10.7-18 8 11.3 11.3-18 11.9 22 3.8-6.8v181.5h-480v-179.5z" fill="#175720"/></svg>
```

(I ran it through a minimizer and then I deleted a bunch of attribute in the `<svg>` tag.) I am using it as a background image and it seems to work fine in IE, Firefox and Chrome on Windows. I am just wondering what all that other information is doing there if it has no effect on the image appearance. Will there be compatibility issues somewhere because I stripped that info out?

UPDATE:
I discovered that actually, for my use case, I need to have `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` or else it won't render in IE or Chrome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Removing the `viewBox` creates a significant semantic difference as the SVG will no longer scale (i.e. be responsive to UA resizes). This only applies if you're viewing the image directly though if you're viewing it as a background-image or via a SVG `<image>` tag or html `<img>` tag then the SVG will be drawn as if it has a `viewBox` of "0 0 width height" unless a `viewBox` is already present.

Removing the `background-color` will mean that the SVG will no longer be opaque when placed on top of something else. Of course if you're not doing that you may not notice.

The `xml:space` attribute only matters if you have text elements in your SVG file.

The rest of the removals are benign if the SVG is inline. Namespace attributes are required if the SVG is a standalone file though which will be the case for a background-image.

Comment: What do you mean that removing the viewBox prevents it from scaling? It seems to scale fine for me in the three browsers I mentioned. But I am only using it as a background image and setting the background size with CSS. However I was having problems with IE until I added the width and height attributes on the SVG.

Answer (score 10):

The reduced version is not valid SVG. It would be considered “just any” XML which happens to have a root element with the name “svg”.

To turn the snippet into *the* SVG there is only one option:

- add an `xmlns` attribute with the proper namespace to the `svg` element (as you discovered)

Adding a `DOCTYPE` to the document is not recommended any more and does not work since at least Chrome 53. Neither is it enough to serve the document as MIME type `image/svg+xml`.

Examples:

- `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">` (SVG version selected by consumer)
- `<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">` (for SVG 1.0)

Use the [W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to check your documents. Make sure to check that the detected doctype is SVG, because the document might still validate, but as general/unknown XML. -- They also have [test pages](https://validator.w3.org/dev/tests/).

---